# How to make nginx redirect based on the value of a header?

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I'm hosting a website behind a Cloudflare proxy, which means that all requests to my server are over port 80, even though Cloudflare handles HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) traffic.

To distinguish between the two, Cloudflare includes an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header which is set to "http" or "https" based on the user's connection.

I would like to redirect every request with an `X-Forwarded-Proto: http` header to the SSL version of my site. How can I achieve this with an nginx configuration?

Comment: Just a quick note that CloudFlare doesn't host your site's content.

Note:PageRules might have worked here as well, since it looks like you're just trying to forward http:// to https://. Information about PageRules: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with an `if` directive. If there is a better way, please let me know, as people say the `if` directive is inefficient. Nginx converts dashes to underscores in headers, so `X-Forwarded-Proto` becomes `$http_x_forwarded_proto`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com; # Replace this with your own hostname
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    # Rest of configuration goes here... 
}
```

Comment: Not sure what people you talk to, but if is not inefficient. It's error prone when abused for purposes outside the realm of rewrites. Read the if is evil article properly to understand it's shortcomings. Your solution is what it was designed for, so it should work just fine.

Comment: Just a small note: If you have multiple server_name values, it's better to replace return string with more generic version: 

return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

Comment: Man, if is evil within nginx ;)
"if" generates number of instances, so nginx get slower and need more memory.

Comment: If is not evil in this case: "The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are: return and rewrite" https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 11):

Try using map directive: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

Something like that...

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto     $php_backend {
    "https"          "https_php_backend named loc";
    default        "default_php_backend named loc";
}
server{
    location / {
         proxy_pass http://$php_backend;
    }
}
```

This code is abstract, but you can try tht way...